# Storing additional information about the user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a recruitment website in wordpress and need a way to store details about the user such as previous experience and qualifications. I want the user to be able to edit this information as soon as they have registered an account (not on the registration page). I've looked at adding user profile fields but I want the information to be isolated from their profile information, in whatever way works. Can anyone recommend any plugins or ways for doing this.

To emphasize, this information should not be related to their contact details which are defaults in wordpress.

Comment: Regarding this question being put on hold, I tried the wordpress overflow site and they couldn't help. The first answer that someone gives on this site is exactly what I needed to know. I wasn't looking for a plugin - I was looking for a solution to my problem. That solution happened to be realised using a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), and follow this steps.

1. Activate plugin.
2. Go to Custom Fields -> Add New
3. Create your fields
4. In the Location box under Rules, select Show this field group if : **(User Add/Edit)** is equal to **All**
5. Publish the fields group

Now if you visit user profiles, you should get the result from my image.

[image: ACF users]

Comment: That's absolutely perfect, thanks! Already using advanced custom fields for something else too.